# Yii2 subquery GROUP BY in active record

Tags: activerecord, yii2, subquery

can I convert this query 
"SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM blog_post ORDER BY data DESC) blog_post GROUP BY blog_id LIMIT 2"

into a Yii2 active record query?

Thx
Ms

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this.
Yii2 gave us a wonderful library support.

You can form **custom** **sql** query and pass this query in `findBySql()` like:

```
$sql = "Some query/nested query";
$result = ModelClass::findBySql($sql);
```

Visit Yii official [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#findBySql()-detail).

Answer (score 0):

> BlogPost::find()
>       ->orderBy('data DESC')
>       ->groupBy('blog_id')
>       ->limit(2)
>       ->all();

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do in this way :

**Ⅰ:create a subQuery where you select from.**

```
$blogPostQuery = BlogPostModel::find()->orderBy(['data' => SORT_DESC]);
```

**Ⅱ:Get activeRecord results.** The ***from*** params is an exist Query.

```
$models = (new yii\db\Query)
->from(['blog_post ' => $blogPostQuery])
->groupBy(['blog_id'])
->limit(2)
->all();
```

ps: 
see [yii\db\query->from()-detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#from()-detail)  in Yii Api;

(public $this from ( $tables )) ***$tables*** can be either a string (e.g. 'user') or an array (e.g. ['user', 'profile']) specifying one or several table names··· or a **sub-query** or DB expression

Have a try!I hope it`s useful for you:))

Comment: I try but in this way the return $models are not an active record but an array.